# Terraform gitlab provider changes commit message

Tags: gitlab, terraform

Is it expected behavior that gitlab provider on terraform adds **[DELETE]** if previous commit message was changed in your tf code?

For example I had a tf file with

```
resource "gitlab-repository-files_gitlab_repository_file" "this" {
    project        = gitlab_project.foo.id
    file_path      = "meow.txt"
    branch         = "main"
    content        = base64encode("hello world")
    author_email   = "meow@catnip.com"
    author_name    = "Meow Meowington"
    commit_message = "feature: add meow file*"
}
```

Then changed it to

```
    commit_message = "[ci skip] terraform templating commit\n\nJob URL: ${local.gitlab_configuration_details.pipeline_job_url}"
```

After the change my commit message on gitlab was **[DELETE]: feature: add meow file**

If this is the expected behavior is there any way around it to prevent the provider from adding comments?

Because I expected after the change for the commit to read on git as "[ci skip] terraform templating commit\n\nJob URL: https:url.com"

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it seems you are not using an official provider, so it would be anybody's guess unless you know how to fix the source code of the provider. :)

Comment: it's not the official one? I was using the one from the TF page https://registry.terraform.io/providers/gitlabhq/gitlab/latest/docs/resources/repository_file 
If this isn't the official one, then could you please link me to the one I should be using?

Comment: Well, that is the official one, but if you take a look at the resource name `gitlab-repository-files_gitlab_repository_file`, when I searched for it, it links to: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/timofurrer/gitlab-repository-files/latest/docs/resources/gitlab_repository_file.

Comment: this one does not seem supported by provider however `The provider provider.gitlab.local does not support resource type
"gitlab-repository-files_gitlab_repository_file".`

Comment: Can you add your `required_providers` block to the question?

Comment: I don't think I'm using any at the moment, just the `provider "gitlab" {
  alias    = "local"
}` block

Comment: That will not work then. You have to specify the right provider in the `required_providers` block (if using Terraform >=0.13.0) and it has to be `gitlab = { source = "gitlabhq/gitlab" }` if you want to use the official one. Unless you have to use locally defined providers for some reason. You can get more details about how to use the official provider when you click on the `Use Provider` purple button in the top right corner.

Comment: yeah, in this case I'm constrained by what the engineering team provides us in the base terraform, I just make use with that, so we have the official one `required_providers {
    gitlab = {
      source = "gitlabhq/gitlab"
      version = "3.12.0"
    }
 `
So best case is to find a workaround for the way provider edits commits

Comment: This looks good then. Why name the resource then after something that does not exist in the official provider? I am kind of confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigating, turns out the [DELETE] gets inserted if you are deleting files. If you just make code changes it will not edit your commit message, this only happens when files are deleted.